# Block Adult app recommendations on play store

Tags: google-play-store

I always get adult app recommendations (under "Recommended for you") on play store though I have never used one. I find it quite embarrassing. Is there any sort of content filtering possible.

Comment: App recommendation are not only listed based on your app usage. It also depends on your friends/followers on G+ circle. So one of your member in your google plus circle is the culprit here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You can use the "Content Filtering" option in the Play Store settings. Set the maturity level to restrict the apps that you don't want to view.

[image: Screenshot_Playstore_settings]

<sup>Screenshot - (Click to enlarge image)</sup>

Comment: what about the web interface?

Comment: I could not find any settings from the web interface. Perhaps the settings from mobile device should do the work.